# Woocommerce - Get Parent Category Name for Sub Category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following code to back button but I want to display the previous category/parent category on the button it does not work as it only shows the current category name in button.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'my_back_button_sample', 11 );
function my_back_button_sample() {
if ( is_product_category() ) {
  //global $product;
  global $wp_query;
    $cate = get_queried_object();
    $cateID = $cate->term_id;
    $product_cat_id = $cateID;
    $id = $product_cat_id;
//if( $term = get_term_by( 'id', $id, 'product_cat' ) ){
//    $test = $term->name;
//  $test .= "-".$term->id;
//}
$parentcats = get_ancestors($product_cat_id,'slug_name', 'product_cat');
    foreach($parentcats as $parentcat){
        if (is_subcategory()) {
  $term = get_queried_object();
  $parent_id = $term->parent;
  $parent_name = $parent_id->name;
  $test = $parent_name;
}
 //   $test = $parentcat->name;
}

  echo '<br/><div class="avia-button-wrap avia-button-left  avia-builder-el-9  el_after_av_button  el_before_av_button ">
  <a class="avia-button   avia-icon_select-no avia-color-blue avia-size-medium avia-position-left " onclick="history.back();" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <span class="avia_iconbox_title">Go Back to '.$test.'</span></a></div> '; 
}
}
```

I had a look at the following code but it only brings up the parent category id and not the name.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53705291/15581453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some changes on your code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'my_back_button_sample', 11 );
function my_back_button_sample() {
if ( is_product_category() ) {
    $curr_cat = get_queried_object();
    if($curr_cat->parent > 0):
        $parentcats = get_ancestors($curr_cat->term_id, 'product_cat');
        foreach($parentcats as $parent):
            $cat = get_term($parent,'product_cat');
            $cat_name = $cat->name;
        endforeach;
    else:
        $cat_name = $curr_cat->name;
    endif;
  echo '<br/><div class="avia-button-wrap avia-button-left  avia-builder-el-9  el_after_av_button  el_before_av_button ">
  <a class="avia-button   avia-icon_select-no avia-color-blue avia-size-medium avia-position-left " onclick="history.back();" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <span class="avia_iconbox_title">Go Back to '.$cat_name.'</span></a></div> '; 
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry to ask you this again, the above works create, just wondering how to make it so that show one category up. example main cat->sub cat-> sub sub cat so if you are in sub sub gat it will show sub cat name and if your are in sub cat it will show main cat name

Comment: So you want something like breadcrumbs ? Check this answer - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/279755/how-to-create-a-breadcrumb-for-pages .

Comment: In a manner of speaking yes, but is in one button form